# Invalid Cast Exception with Update Panel

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

**On Button Click**

```
Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
        MsgBox("INSIDE")
        If SocialAuthUser.IsLoggedIn Then
            Dim accountId As Integer = BLL.getAccIDFromSocialAuthSession
            Dim AlbumID As Integer = BLL.createAndReturnNewAlbumId(txtStoryTitle.Text.Trim, "")
            Dim URL As String = BLL.getAlbumPicUrl(txtStoryTitle.Text.Trim)
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            dt.Columns.Add("PictureID")
            dt.Columns.Add("AccountID")
            dt.Columns.Add("AlbumID")
            dt.Columns.Add("URL")
            dt.Columns.Add("Thumbnail")
            dt.Columns.Add("Description")
            dt.Columns.Add("AlbumCover")
            dt.Columns.Add("Tags")
            dt.Columns.Add("Votes")
            dt.Columns.Add("Abused")
            dt.Columns.Add("isActive")
            Dim Row As DataRow

            Dim uniqueFileName As String = ""
            If Session("ID") Is Nothing Then
                lblMessage.Text = "You don't seem to have uploaded any pictures."
                Exit Sub
            Else


**Dim FileCount As Integer = Request.Form(Request.Form.Count - 2)**
                Dim FileName, TargetName As String
                Try
                    Dim Path As String = Server.MapPath(BLL.getAlbumPicUrl(txtStoryTitle.Text.Trim))
                    If Not IO.Directory.Exists(Path) Then
                        IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Path)
                    End If
                    Dim StartIndex As Integer
                    Dim PicCount As Integer
                    For i As Integer = 0 To Request.Form.Count - 1
                        If Request.Form(i).ToLower.Contains("jpg") Or Request.Form(i).ToLower.Contains("gif") Or Request.Form(i).ToLower.Contains("png") Then
                            StartIndex = i + 1
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
                    For i As Integer = StartIndex To Request.Form.Count - 4 Step 3
                        FileName = Request.Form(i)
                        '## If part here is not kaam ka..but still using it for worst case scenario
                        If IO.File.Exists(Path & FileName) Then
                            TargetName = Path & FileName
                            'MsgBox(TargetName & "--- 1")
                            Dim j As Integer = 1
                            While IO.File.Exists(TargetName)
                                TargetName = Path & IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileName) & "(" & j & ")" & IO.Path.GetExtension(FileName)
                                j += 1
                            End While
                        Else
                            uniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid.ToString & "__" & FileName
                            TargetName = Path & uniqueFileName

                        End If
                        IO.File.Move(Server.MapPath("~/TempUploads/" & Session("ID") & "/" & FileName), TargetName)
                        PicCount += 1
                        Row = dt.NewRow()
                        Row(1) = accountId
                        Row(2) = AlbumID
                        Row(3) = URL & uniqueFileName
                        Row(4) = ""
                        Row(5) = "No Desc"
                        Row(6) = "False"
                        Row(7) = ""
                        Row(8) = "0"
                        Row(9) = "0"
                        Row(10) = "True"
                        dt.Rows.Add(Row)
                    Next
                    If BLL.insertImagesIntoAlbum(dt) Then

                        lblMessage.Text = PicCount & IIf(PicCount = 1, " Picture", " Pictures") & " Saved!"
                        lblMessage.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Black
                        Dim db As SqlDatabase = Connection.connection
                        Using cmd As DbCommand = db.GetSqlStringCommand("SELECT PictureID,URL FROM AlbumPictures WHERE AlbumID=@AlbumID AND AccountID=@AccountID")
                            db.AddInParameter(cmd, "AlbumID", Data.DbType.Int32, AlbumID)
                            db.AddInParameter(cmd, "AccountID", Data.DbType.Int32, accountId)
                            Using ds As DataSet = db.ExecuteDataSet(cmd)
                                If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
                                    ListView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
                                    ListView1.DataBind()
                                Else
                                    lblMessage.Text = "No Such Album Exists."
                                End If

                            End Using
                        End Using
                        'WebNavigator.GoToResponseRedirect(WebNavigator.URLFor.ReturnUrl("~/Memories/SortImages.aspx?id=" & AlbumID))
                    Else
                        'TODO:we'll show some error msg
                    End If

                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.Message)
                    lblMessage.Text = "Oo Poop!!"
                End Try
            End If
        Else
            WebNavigator.GoToResponseRedirect(WebNavigator.URLFor.LoginWithReturnUrl("~/Memories/CreateAlbum.aspx"))
            Exit Sub
        End If

    End Sub
```

The above code works fine.I have added an Update Panel in the page to avoid post back, But when i add the button click as a trigger

```
<Triggers>
   <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" />
</Triggers>
```

in the update panel to avoid post back, i get the following error.This happens when i add the button click as a Trigger to the update panel.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Request.Form` returns a `NameValueCollection` which is accessible by the  name of the key or the `int` indexer. It always returns a `String` and not an `Integer`.

```
Dim FileCount As String = Request.Form(Request.Form.Count - 2)
```

Comment: But why does it work when i do not add the button as a trigger to the update panel??

Comment: @user1593175: 1. i strongly recommend to set `OPTION STRICT` to `ON`. Then it would not even compile. 2. The reason why it works is that the value in `Request.Forms` returns something that is not convertible to an `Integer` with your trigger. You should use the debugger to compare the two values with and without trigger. You might also want to use the name instead of the index which is less error-prone.

Comment: When i change FileCount to String `Dim FileCount As String` i get `FileCount=True` , but without adding Button to update panel trigger with `Dim FileCount As Integer` i get `FileCount=15`

Comment: @user1593175: and `"True"` cannot be converted implicitely to an integer whereas `"15"` will be converted to `15`. Just use the name of  the form variable instead of the index in the form-collection and change your `OPTION STRICT` setting in "Tools/Options...VB Defaults".

Comment: I have used the code from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/240403/Multiple-Fileupload-for-ASP-NET-with-Client-Side-R) Last code block..can you please explain me why does the author subtract 2 from the `Request.Form.Count`

Comment: How do i get the name of the form variable? Excuse me if i am being too stupid.

Comment: @user1593175: I'm not sure which variable you are looking for. Use `String.Join(",", Request.Form.AllKeys)` to see all keys and pick out what you need.

Answer (score 0):

This is all intuition from the exception message, but on the line

```
FileCount As Integer = Request.Form(Request.Form.Count - 2)
```

It looks like `Request.Form(Request.Form.Count - 2)` is a string, and you're trying trying to assign a it to an integer type.

I don't know what you're trying to do, but the string looks like it contains "true"  do you want the following?

```
FileCount As Integer += Boolean.Parse(Request.Form(Request.Form.Count - 2)) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: Yes you are right. But the exact same code works when i do not add the button as a trigger to the update panel??

Comment: @user1593175  i'm guessing that it works because the incorrect code doesn't execute

Comment: I have used the code from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/240403/Multiple-Fileupload-for-ASP-NET-with-Client-Side-R) Last code block..can you please explain me why does the author subtract 2 from the `Request.Form.Count`